# How can I use the method I created to modify one of the attributes of the objects in an array?

Tags: java

I am trying to modify the prices of the objects in my cellphone class using the ModifyPhonePrices I created but the method is not working whenever I am invoking it.Please help!

```
import java.util.Random;
public class ModifyCellPhones {

    public static double ModifyPhonePrices (double[][] cellarr, double ov, double nv)
    {
        int ctr=0, i, j;

        for (i=0; i < cellarr[i].length ; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j < cellarr[j].length; j++)
            {
            if (cellarr[i][j] == ov)//if the content of the index i in the array 
            {                   //equals that of the old value then     
                cellarr[i][j] = nv;//it will be replaced by the new value
                ctr++;//keeps track of the changes performed
                System.out.println("The value changed was found at index" + "[" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "]");
            }
            }
        }
        return ctr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int i, j, counter = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();//random object that will assign random values to the phones that are uninitialized

        CellPhone [][] cp = new CellPhone [10][10];//creation of two-dimensional array

        //creating 90 cellphones using the for loop

                for (i=0 ;i < 10; i++)
                {
                    for (j=0; j < 10; j++)
                    {
                    cp[i][j] = new CellPhone ("Blackberry",569874132,300.00);
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println(cp[i][j]);
                    }
                }


         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Here are the contents of the array; only the prices of the contents are shown:");
         System.out.println();

        //setting the prices using the random class
        for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                 cp[i][j].setprice(rand.nextInt(300));
                 System.out.printf("%8.2f",cp[i][j].getprice());
            }
        System.out.println();
        }

        //creating a another array to copy the price content of the cellphone array

        double [][] arr = new double [10][10];
                for (i=0; i<10; i++)
                {
                    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
                    {
                        arr[i][j] = cp[i][j].getprice();
                    }
                }

        //modifying values using the ModifyPhonePrices method created

        counter = ModifyCellPhones.ModifyPhonePrices(arr[][] ,150.00,200.00);

        if  (counter > 0)
        {
            System.out.println (counter + "changes are made.");
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
for (i=0; i < cellarr[i].length ; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j < cellarr[j].length; j++)
```

should be

```
for (i=0; i < cellarr.length; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j < cellarr[i].length; j++)
```

What I think is happening (although you don't specify) is that when `j` gets to `10`, `cellar[j]` throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You should never say "It is not working". You should always say what happens, and include the exact error message and the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your issue (as also pointed out by [pbabcdefp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3973077/pbabcdefp)) is that you're using the wrong values for sentinels in your loops:

```
for (i=0; i < cellarr[i].length ; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < cellarr[j].length; j++) {
```

should be

```
for (i=0; i < cellarr.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < cellarr[i].length; j++) {
```

---

Next, you're returning a double instead of an int from `ModifyPhonePrices` (which should be `modifyPhonePrices` according to convention).  This is an integer count of the number of changes made, a `double` just doesn't make sense (especially given that `ctr` is declared as an `int`).

---

Next, as mentioned by [imad3v](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3147779/imad3v), your method call should read

```
counter = ModifyPhonePrices(arr, 150.00, 200.00);
```

instead of

```
counter = ModifyPhonePrices(arr[][], 150.00, 200.00);
```

---

Lastly, `double` for currency is a bad idea.  Have a look at [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Those changes should yield working code.